# Can client updates / upgrades be pushed over the ETH network?

Tags: events, network, clients, upgrading

Is it possible for ETH clients to securely receive a live push notification/version update like the way OSX, MacOS does?

What are the pros and cons? : )

There could be a contract filter to gain prior approval to automatically upgrade version once it becomes available. Also a feature to signal, for whatever reason, if one wishes to remain on an older version.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum smart contracts support events for which client libraries lik web3.js, web3.py have easy-to-use bindings.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events

However this is extreme inefficient way to communicate as all notifications would be have to be written to a public blockchain. Storage in public blockchain may be 1000-10000 more expensive than with other methods.

Instead, you should use standard web push protocols for push notifications. They are free, scaleable and work offline:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API

Comment: Thanks Mkko, that's great point - and like you say currently a cost effective method.